# How to write a JavaScript function for different type of inputs?

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

how can write a function of JavaScript for output the same result 5?

Function `sum(2,5)` or function `sum((2)(3))` ?

Thank you all

Comment: What does `sum((2)(3))` mean?

Comment: I suppose the first example should be `sum(2, 3)`, right?

Comment: @Ian did you mean `sum(2)(3)`?

Comment: you just can't pass args with the second syntax.

Comment: Sorry for not making a good interpretation. It is a question given in an assessment exam. It is saying that if the user input parameters both in function sum(2,3) or sum((2)(3)) can return the output 5. How to work out this function?

Comment: I think the question should be how to handle a function with different parameters input format . If SUM(2,3), then it is simple. But how to handle an input with SUM((2)(3)) by using the same function?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `curry` to make such functions like `sum(2)(3)`

```
sum = (n) => (m) => n + m
sum(3)(4) === 7 // true
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function sum(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2
}

//calling:
sum(2, 3) //returns 5;
sum(2, 5) //return 7;
```

Thats all i can guess from your given information.

Comment: If you don't have enough info ask in comments, please. Don't just guess.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm just trying to help.

Comment: That's appreciated, don't take this the wrong way :)